# Compile error when I install HAWQ on Centos7:

Tags: c, autotools, hawq

I want to install HAWQ on my Centos7.5 
When I run: `./configure` and `make -j8`
I got this one:

```
g++ --shared -o cwrapper.o cwrapper.cpp -Lformat -lorc_format
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccjv719I.o: relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `_Z9func_testv' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Nonrepresentable section on output
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

If I run `make install` next
I can't get all files in hawq

but When I retry `./configure`,`make -j8`,`make install` 
`ccjv719I.o` will change ,maybe `cc4U41Di.o` or others

When I run :`./configure CFLAGES=-fPIC CXXFLAGES=-fPIC --enable-shared`
I got the same error.
What should I do?

Comment: You should file a bug report against HAWQ. An Autotools-based build system ought not to suffer from such an issue.  It is not out of the question that the blame is somehow local to your computer, but the HAWQ folks are better equipped to sort that out than SO is.

Comment: Thank you very much! I use another source code on GitHub and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
./configure --prefix=/hawq/install/path --with-python --with-perl
```